# Como faço, no postman, para validar que num array "data" todos os elementos contém um valor específico no campo "name"?

Tags: javascript, array, postman

```
Recebo como resposta de uma requisição, o seguinte response:

"data": [
    {
        "id": 148,
        "name": "Amrita Naik",
        "email": "amrita_naik@oconnell.net",
        "gender": "Female",
        "status": "Inactive",
        "created_at": "2021-01-25T03:50:06.849+05:30",
        "updated_at": "2021-01-25T03:50:06.849+05:30"
    },
    {
        "id": 156,
        "name": "Dron Naik",
        "email": "naik_dron@barrows-cartwright.net",
        "gender": "Male",
        "status": "Active",
        "created_at": "2021-01-25T03:50:06.975+05:30",
        "updated_at": "2021-01-25T03:50:06.975+05:30"
    },
    {
        "id": 178,
        "name": "Rukmin Naik",
        "email": "rukmin_naik@farrell-moore.biz",
        "gender": "Male",
        "status": "Active",
        "created_at": "2021-01-25T03:50:07.351+05:30",
        "updated_at": "2021-01-25T03:50:07.351+05:30"
    },
```

Eu preciso validar que todos os campos name possui o nome "Naik". Apesar do meu teste passar, não consigo conferir, pois não printa nada no console do postman. Segue o que eu tentei fazer:

```
pm.test("Deve validar o nome", function () {
const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
for(var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].name);
}
    pm.expect(jsonData.data[i].name).to.include("Naik");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode usar o método [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), que testa se todos os elementos dentro de um array atendem uma condição:

```js
var name = "Rukmin Naik";

var array = `{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":148,
         "name":"Amrita Naik",
         "email":"amrita_naik@oconnell.net",
         "gender":"Female",
         "status":"Active",
         "created_at":"2021-01-25T03:50:06.849+05:30",
         "updated_at":"2021-01-25T03:50:06.849+05:30"
      },
      {
         "id":156,
         "name":"Dron Naik",
         "email":"naik_dron@barrows-cartwright.net",
         "gender":"Male",
         "status":"Active",
         "created_at":"2021-01-25T03:50:06.975+05:30",
         "updated_at":"2021-01-25T03:50:06.975+05:30"
      },
      {
         "id":178,
         "name":"Rukmin Naik",
         "email":"rukmin_naik@farrell-moore.biz",
         "gender":"Male",
         "status":"Active",
         "created_at":"2021-01-25T03:50:07.351+05:30",
         "updated_at":"2021-01-25T03:50:07.351+05:30"
      }
   ]
}`;
    
 var obj = JSON.parse(array);
 
if (!obj.data.every(e => e.name === name)) {
   console.log("name invalido");
}

if (!obj.data.every(e => e.status === "Active")) {
   console.log(" status invalido");
}
```

Pra demostrar quando está ok, coloquei uma validação para "status" e alterei para todos "Active"

Comment: Obrigada! Consegui resolver da seguinte forma: 

pm.test("Deve validar o nome", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.data.length; i++) {
        var obj = jsonData.data[i].name;
        console.log(obj);
        pm.expect(obj).to.include("Naik");
    }
});
Assim todos os nomes que contenham o nome "Naik" são validados.